# Unwanted caption indentation with longtable, when using width in captionsetup

Tags: captions, memoir, indentation, longtable

I get an indented caption if I use `width=0.9\linewidth` in the `captionsetup`. Then the `longtable` caption centres or indents and there is no way to get it to align flush left to the table. However, `width` works fine with other tables. I use it because some captions in my document are very long but I didn't want them to go all the way to the right margin of the document. I have tried using `margin` in the `captionsetup`, but that causes the same problem. I have also tried using a negative indentation setting in the captionsetup, but that only effects the second line of the caption, not the table numbering.

Here, a screenshot and MWE:
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{threeparttable} % for table notes
\usepackage{threeparttablex} % for longtable notes
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx} % align numbers by decimal point
\usepackage{lipsum}

%setup page
\settypeblocksize{237mm}{150mm}{*} % size of text block on page
\setulmargins{3.5cm}{*}{*} % sets start of text on page after ruled header
\setheadfoot{\onelineskip}{2\onelineskip}
\setheaderspaces{2cm}{*}{*} % start of rule header line on page
\setlrmarginsandblock{3.5cm}{2.5cm}{*} % left and right margins
\checkandfixthelayout

\sisetup{detect-family, add-integer-zero = false, group-digits = false}%

%adding width indents/centers longtable caption
\captionsetup[table]{textfont=it, justification=raggedright, singlelinecheck=off, format=plain, labelsep=newline, skip=5pt, width=0.9\linewidth}

%excluding width works
%\captionsetup[longtable]{justification=raggedright, labelsep=newline, singlelinecheck=off, textfont=it, skip=5pt, format=plain}

\begin{document}

%normal table
\begin{table}[!htb]
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Evaluation of some contexts based on some coordinates}
\label{some_tabel1}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{%
    X
    r
    p{1mm}
    p{20mm}
    S[table-format=2.0, table-column-width=12mm]
    S[table-format=2.0, table-column-width=12mm]
    S[table-format=2.0, table-column-width=12mm]
    S[table-format=2.0, table-column-width=12mm]
    }
\toprule
\multirow{2}[2]{*}{Sample context}
& \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textit{N}}
&
& \multirow{2}[2]{1.8cm}{Proposed construct}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Some location}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Another location} \\
\cmidrule(r){5-6}
\cmidrule(l){7-8}
& & & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{n}}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\%}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{n}}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\%} \\
\midrule
Item 1   &  $54$   && Low     &  23 &  43  & 31  &  57  \\
Item 2   &  $73$   && High    &  60 &  82  & 13  &  18  \\
Item 3   &  $80$   && High    &  72 &  90  &  8  &  10  \\
Item 4   &  $83$   && Medium  &  72 &  87  & 11  &  13  \\
Item 5   & $159$  && Rare    & 148 &  93  & 11  &  7   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
\small{\textit{Note}. Some further notes here.}
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

%longtable
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{TableNotes}[para,flushleft]
\small{\textit{Note}. Some note text here.}
\end{TableNotes}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2mm} %add row padding before midrule
\begin{longtable}[!htb]{
        >{\raggedright}p{0.5cm}
        >{\raggedright}p{3.1cm} 
        >{\raggedright}p{8.5cm} 
        p{1.5cm}
    }
\caption[]{Severity of identified problems and proposed changes}
\label{some_lable2}\\
\toprule
\\ [-1.8\normalbaselineskip]
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Change} & Justification & Severity\\ %the first header
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption{Severity of identified problems and proposed changes (cont.)}\\
\toprule
\\ [-1.8\normalbaselineskip]
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Change} & Justification & Severity\\ %the following header(s)
\midrule
\endhead
\midrule
\\[-1.8\normalbaselineskip]
\multicolumn{4}{r}{\textit{continued}}
\endfoot
\\[-1\normalbaselineskip]
\bottomrule
\insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot
1. & Bullet point 1 and some extra sample text & \lipsum[1] & High \\
2. & Bullet point 2 & \lipsum[2] & Medium\\
3. & Bullet point 3 & \lipsum[3] & Low\\
\end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't see a problem with either table if you remove the width specification.  Note that Table 02 is too wide for the page, but if you remove 3mm it works fine.  BTW, since longtable is NOT a float, what is with the `[!htb]`?

Comment: Yes, but I'd rather not remove the width specification, as I have a lot of tabularx tables with long caption texts ... hence my post :)

Comment: Another way to formulate what I am asking is "Why does the width attribute in captionsetup not work with longtable?"

Comment: One of the things longtable does is adjust the width of the caption to match the width of the table.  If you specify \captionsetup{margin=0pt} inside longtable, it will disable the width setting (locally) and keep all the others.

Comment: Aha!  Use `margin={0pt,.1\linewidth}`.  At least it works on the first page.